# Why i should call Control.Invoke from non-ui thread?

Tags: winforms, winapi

Why i should call Control.Invoke from non-ui thread? As i know any manipulations with control are the messages to control. So when i call, for example TextBox.Text = "text", it will produce message SendMessage(TextBox.Hanlde...). That message will be queued into UI thread message queue and dispatched by UI thread. Why i have to call invoke, even it will produce the same message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons MS developers made this restriction:

1. Some UI functions have access to thread-local storage (TLS). Calling these functions from another thread gives incorrect results on TLS operations.
2. Calling all UI-related functions from the same thread automatically serializes them, this is thread-safe and doesn't require synchronization.

From our point of view, we just need to follow these rules.

Comment: Ok, how about STA activex components, maybe some controls is COM+ objects?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. We are talking about Windows Forms controls. Maybe some of them use COM internally, but this is not part of their public interface.

Comment: I mean, this restriction also guarantee executing UI COM objects from STA threads.

Comment: Maybe. I didn't think about COM STA, this is one more advantage (for Windows Forms developers, not users).

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot directly access UI controls from threads other than the thread they were created on.  `Control.Invoke` will marshal your call onto the correct thread - allowing you to make a call from another thread onto the UI thread without needing to know yourself what the UI thread is or how to perform the marshalling.

**Update:** to answer your question, you don't *have* to use `Control.Invoke` - if you have code to marshal your call onto the correct thread and post a message to the message pump - then use that.  This, however, is known as re-inventing the wheel.  Unless you are doing something that changes the behaviour.

Comment: I know how works Control.Invoke, i ask why i can't call directly. Anyway TextBox.Text will put message to UI thread message queue